# Delete all repeated values

Tags: r, vector

If I have a vector:

```
x <- c(5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 2, 1, 9, 9)
```

How can I make another vector that contains elements that were never repeated? In this case it would be: `c(6, 1)` (because 5, 2, and 9 are repeated)

Comment: You're asking about a vector while the linked question is for a data.frame, but the answer seems to apply fine both places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test <- c(5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 2, 1, 9, 9)
setdiff(test, test[duplicated(test)])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
vector.a <- c(5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 2, 1, 9, 9)

not.reap <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(vector.a)){
  not.reap[i] <- !(vector.a[i] %in% vector.a[-i])
}
vector.a[not.reap]
```